# sphinx - autodoc for two modules with the same name and different path

Tags: python, python-sphinx, autodoc

I use sphinx for documenting a large number of python files, which are spread inside a vast hierarchy of directories. Also, many of the files are with the same name (but exist in different paths).
I tried to create different .rst files and use :include: with different path for each file, and then put all of the .rst in the main rst (index.rst) - but autodoc related only for the first .rst file and for the rest of the files it related as the first one (when i tried to do autoclass for a class not from the first file, it couldn't find it because it thought I was in the first file...).

**My Question**:  is there a way to make the autodoc relate to files/modules as different files/modules although they have the same name?  (changing their names is not an option).  Also, is there a way to express the file-directories-hierarchy in the generated html file?

Comment: So you have a number of packages then? The Python modules should be distinguished by different “dotted module names”, such as `pkg1.mod1` and `pkg2.mod1` etc. Does that not work for you? See https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages.

Comment: This does not appear to work in the Sphinx syntax, such as `.. automodule:: pkg.mod`.